# Why does Rotterdam not want me to lean against buildings?

Tags: legal, netherlands, rotterdam

I'm going to Rotterdam for [an Ingress event](http://events.ingress.com/xmanomalies/aegis-nova/Rotterdam) at the end of May. This event expects somewhere between 2000 and 4000 people from all over the world, but mostly central Europe. Because of recent terror events and because there are also a lot of other events in the city that day, the metropolitan police agreed on a code of conduct with the local organizers of the Ingress event. Besides a few others, the rules include:

> - No alcohol in the streets within the city center
> - No leaning against buildings or shouting across the street.

Why would leaning against buildings be a problem for the police? Is this to protect residents from being bothered by tourists, or has it maybe got to do with old buildings?

The police has also received screenshots of the Ingress mobile phone application and we were told to show our phones on request so they can distinguish us from groups of party-goers.

Comment: Because builinds in Rotterdam would fall over if 2000 people leaned on them at once? More seriously, I suspect they want to reduce "loitering"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Dutch laws.

Comment: @JonathanReez I tried finding references that this is actually a law, but it seems to be temporary for that weekend, which makes it relevant to travelers that go to those events. Imagine everyone being arrested for leaning against a building in one of the biggest ports in the world all the time.

Comment: "Why X is a law" is only relevant to this site if "X" is a travel-related law. However you can change your question to "Is it true that I can't lean against buildings?".

Comment: @Jonathan how would that edit make it more on-topic? I can see that my current wording leaves room for a lot of speculation, but your suggestion would just make it a "who does the most reasearch" question I believe.

Comment: I'm not sure it's truly a law or anything with official force vs something the event organizers have agreed with the police to include in a code of conduct for the event. It's entirely possible that someone just thought it sounded good and stuck it in the list: "hmm, we should tell all these people to be orderly; what do orderly people do? Well they don't drink or shout or loiter around leaning on buildings that's for sure."

Comment: Are you sure it's not something that went wrong in translation? Is the code of conduct available in Dutch too?

Comment: @Berwyn I don't know. I only have the English text that I partly quoted above, which is from a closed g+ community. I'm trying to find a document that I can link to.

Comment: FWIW, there are no terms and conditions or code of conduct that you have to accept when purchasing a ticket (or getting a free one), so just go ahead and lean on those walls!

Comment: So, if I visit Rotterdam on that day, not being part of this event, and lean against a building, what will happen?

Comment: @MastaBaba either the building will fall down or you will be arrseted, I think.

Comment: @ZachLipton OK, maybe it's not literally a law. But the question is still, "Why is it that people in Rotterdam will be arrested for leaning against buildings on a particular date?" That isn't a question about travel; it's a question about something that looks like a law, swims like a law and quacks like a law.

Comment: @CMaster: I find that highly unlikely, though. On either count.

Comment: I agree this isn't a question about travel. I also think Wileke's answer is about as good as you're going to get unless you go to the trouble of asking either the Niantic staff or the Rotterdam police who set these rules exactly what they were thinking. I also think it's unlikely that people will be arrested just for leaning on a building or briefly shouting across the street; it is more likely that they would simply be asked to stop, and perhaps reported to event organizers if needed.

Comment: @zach ok, convinced.

Comment: Asking for dog training in Japan was considered 'on topic' without the OP telling anything about traveling to or in Japan. Here the OP is in Rotterdam as a short term visitor, and asking about a rule that is not easy to find on internet, not even when you do speak the language. I believe this is a real travel questions and should stay open.

Comment: @Willeke "Some other question wasn't closed as off-topic" is never a reason to keep a question open. There could be all kinds of reasons the question you refer to wasn't closed: perhaps not enough people noticed it, for example.

Comment: It was discussed and people (enough to keep it open) claimed it was a travel Q. This is much more a travel Q in my opinion.

Comment: I think the community can decide if my question is on topic or not. If someone feels strong enough about it to take that discussion to meta they are invited to do so. If there are suggestions for making it more on-topic that include explanations why this is the case, I am happy to edit and invite the community to provide answers to that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have done an internet search in Dutch, I did not find the 'do not lean against buildings' for Rotterdam, nor in general neither for this one event.

In the Netherlands it is quite common for cities to have special rules 'with status of law' for special events.
The Ingress event is quite big and the city officials will likely not want it to get out of hand.

I do not expect them to arrest people who lean against the buildings, but they might have police or security crews in the streets and ask people to move on if the crowds seem to be overwhelming for the street or blocking the normal activities for the street (like shopping).

Comment: Moving along people playing an Ingress anomaly cluster is not going to make them very popular with the crowd. We tend to stand around in **huge** groups at exactly one spot for ten minutes at those events. Luckily, most of them are peaceful nerds.

Comment: 10 minutes is not going to be a problem, specially not if the police/security know what to expect. But having huge groups leaning against windows (shop fronts) might have risks, which is why they might have included that rule.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you for researching.